# SOAP server in python that also generates WSDL

Tags: python, web-services, iis, soap, wsdl

I'm looking to implement a SOAP web service in python on top of IIS. Is there a recommended library that would take a given Python class and expose its functions as web methods? It would be great if said library would also auto-generate a WSDL file based on the interface.

Comment: I recommend you to use `Spyne`; I have implemented a SOAP web server with this library along with `Django`. It provides you a lot of facilities.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article by Doug Hellmann that evaluates various SOAP Tools

- http://doughellmann.com/2009/09/01/evaluating-tools-for-developing-with-soap-in-python.html

Other ref:

- http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices
- http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Assaf Lavie: Edited my answer to have his full name. We have virtualenvwrapper, a useful tool thanks to him. A python contributor that you would like to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/stepank/pyws, it can expose python functions as SOAP methods and provides WSDL description. I've just released version 1.0, it's interoperability was tested on several clients, so it seems to be quite friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SOAPpy (http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/).  It allows you to expose your functions as web methods, but you have to add a line of code (manually) to register your function with the exposed web service.  It is fairly easy to do.  Also, it doesn't auto generate wsdl for you.
Here's an example of how to create your web service, and expose a function:

```
    server = SOAPpy.SOAPServer(("", 8080))
    server.registerFunction(self.hello)
```

Comment: do you know anything that can generate the WSDL as well. It's seems like such a shame that registering a function is so easy but then you need to go edit some XML file to publish its interface...

Comment: It's not pretty, but to get started, what I've done is go into Visual Studio and created a web service with the exact same signature and have VS.NET generate the wsdl. I do recall having to override some webmethod attribute to make it match the way SOAPpy exposes things (eg. [SoapRpcMethod()]). Also need to add the following attribute before the Class containing the .NET web method: [SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle=SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]